# How to access a list of double values?

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have a list of values of the type double[] defined as `List <double[]> points`

The list is given a set of points in the form `[[x0, y0], [x1, y1], [x2, y2]...]`

How do I access the values x0,y0,x1,y1... using a for loop?

I can access the values in an array using a for loop but can't get my head around how to do so if they are in a List of arrays.

Comment: just traverse the list with foreach.

Comment: "defined as List <double[]> points" There's your problem immediately. Use `List<List<Double>>`.

Comment: @Michael That's equally bad. There is no point in using a collection/array for a fixed number of values per item. So OP should rather use one of the existing `Point` classes or write his own one.

Comment: @Tom It's not equally bad. Mixing arrays and lists should always be avoided. But yes, a point class is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

5tingr4y's answer is correct, but assuming that all arrays have the same length (2) then you do not need the nested loop.

```
for (double[] pair : points) {
    double x = pair[0];
    double y = pair[1];
    // Do things with x and y
}
```

Alternatively given the use case in your example, you could use a class like [`Point`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/awt/Point.html) and [`Point2D.Double`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.Double.html) from the awt library, or [`Point2D`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/geometry/Point2D.html) from the JavaFX library to store your pair of x and y values. Or you can even make your own class. e.g.

```
public class MyPoint {
    private double x, y;

    public MyPoint(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }
}
```

Example use of `MyPoint`, and pretty much the same for the library classes mentioned previously.

```
List<MyPoint> points = new ArrayList<>();
points.add(new MyPoint(5, 10));
for (MyPoint p : points) {
    double x = p.getX();
    double y = p.getY();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a nested loop:

```
for(double[] dArr: points) { //iterate through all arrays in the list
    for(double d: dArr) { //iterate through all doubles in the current array
        //your code
    }
}
```